# Gas pressure along the axis in effusion

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, gas

I'm trying to approximate the pressure P along the axis x, i.e. P(x), for the following setup. At one end of a cylinder a gas is inserted (at some pressure, let's call it P0). At the other end of the cylinder is a small hole, through which the gas exits (effusion) into vacuum. I assume that hole is small enough such that not all the gas exits steadily but some of it accumulates near the hole. Closer to the hole, higher the pressure of the gas.

I think the problem is very similar to the atmospheric air subject to gravity (closer the air to the ground - larger the pressure) and [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula) the P(x) dependence for this case. However, I have troubles to link between the gravity in barometric case to pressure gradient in my case. If I use the [presure-gradient force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure-gradient_force) I get back to the barometric formula since it's how the latter is derived.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I don't see the mechanism you are proposing for the pressure gradient, and I question whether one would exist. In the atmosphere, there is the external force of gravity pulling there air downwards, but there's no external force in your setup. And then the pressure is high near the exit hole?

Comment: I added an image of what I mean. On the left side pressure is P0, on the right side it's 0. So there is a pressure difference, thus force, under which particles of a gas are moving to the right. If hole was big enough, the flow was steady and pressure was uniform. But the hole is small, particles are accumulated near the hole, thus density/pressure there is higher than P0. This is similar to the atmosphere in a sense that the role of gravity (external force) is played by pressure difference.

Comment: But why is the gas accumulating at the right hand side? It would make sense if there was some type of field, say, pulling them there, but you don't mention such a thing. If they were free of an external field, the gas would distribute uniformly, not accumulate on the right hand side.

Comment: I agree with tom10. The presence of more closely-packed gas molecules is associated with higher pressure (at constant temperature), not smaller. I would expect a fairly constant pressure (and particle density) everywhere except in an area close to the hole, where a strong gradient radiating inwards from the exit point would develop.

Comment: Ok, thank you both.